# Dynamically get textbox's name

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, expression-blend-4

```
private void txt_f_name_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string textbox_name_1,textbox_name_2;            

    TextBox textbox_1 = (TextBox)e.Source;
    textbox_name1= textbox_1.Text;

    TextBox textbox_2 = (TextBox)e.OriginalSource;
    textbox_name_2;= textbox_2.Text;            
}
```

now both `textbox_name_1` and `textbox_name_2` are getting same result.

if i try to get another thing like text,with etc... these are also getting the same result....

but i think there may be some difference.

so,i want to know the major difference between `e.source` and `e.OriginalSource`.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases source and original source differ.

> Common cases where the source may be adjusted include content elements
>   inside a content model for a control (the contents of a list item, for
>   instance, will report the list item element as the Source and the
>   actual element within the list item will be the OriginalSource.

ref from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx):

i'm not sure what you try to do with your code. to check source and original source text property do like below, and you can do the same thing by adding list view with items having text box.

```
private void txt_f_name_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string textbox_name_1,textbox_name_2;            

    TextBox textbox_1 = (TextBox)e.Source;
    textbox_name1= textbox_1.Text;

    TextBox textbox_2 = (TextBox)e.OriginalSource;
    textbox_name_2 = textbox_2.Text;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

This originalsource property acquires its value once, before the class event handlers or any instance handlers are invoked, and is never adjusted past this point.

With routed events other events may have fired before your handler.

[OriginalSourece][1]
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx